# Firebase function not being triggered when data base is written to

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My database is structured as follows Collection("Message").Document("message")

But in reality, I want any change in the database's main collection to be monitored—when a document is added. I added the message document because I thought that maybe the function wasn't being called since my documents are the auto-generated ones. However, the problem persists...

Just for background I am an iOS developer, so perhaps I am doing something wrong here:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendPushNotifications = functions.database.ref('/Messages/{message}').onCreate((snapshot,context) => {

    console.log(snapshot);
    console.log(context);

    var topic = "/topics/sentMessages";

    var payload = {
        data: {
            message : 'You recieved a new message!'
        }
    }

    return  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic,payload).then((response) => {

        return response;
    })
})
```

For additional background: The application receives push notifications fine when using the console whether it be directly to the testing device or using topics. This problem is strictly when writing to firebase Firestore...

Answer (score 1):

When you said "Collection("Message").Document("message")" that suggested to me that you're using Firestore as your database.  However, your function is targeting changes to Realtime Database, which is a completely different thing.  `functions.database` builds function for Realtime Database.  `functions.firestore` builds functions for Firestore.  You will want to read the [documentation on Firetore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to learn how to write them.

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately.  Stack Overflow is not good for solving ongoing series of problems.

Comment: Doug, I resolved that problem and also changed my quotations from ' to " but still not triggering...

Comment: Please don't rewrite questions like that.  You just invalidated my answer.  The old Q and A might have been helpful to someone else later.  It's better to post new questions with new details.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at actually asking questions on here.

Comment: Editing questions is good for fixing typos, reformatting, and clarifying your question in response to comments, but it's not good for iterating a bunch of different problems.